# How to display linestring geojson and attach a popup?

Tags: popup, leaflet, geojson

Using Leaflet, how can I show a linestring geojson and then attach a popup to it when selected.

Data below:

```
var aT0625124projectlimits = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -76.60064603515116,
            39.2066837882357
          ],
          [
            -76.6008535248809,
            39.20570326707206
          ],
          [
            -76.60105527000235,
            39.20472201267091
          ],
          [
            -76.60125126636073,
            39.203740045211056
          ],
          [
            -76.60144150991955,
            39.20275738488675
          ],
          [
            -76.60162599676089,
            39.201774051907414
          ],
          [
            -76.6018047230853,
            39.2007900664971
          ],
          [
            -76.60299312179492,
            39.193882732157995
          ],
          [
            -76.60483513954705,
            39.18255323412114
          ],
          [
            -76.60489278228994,
            39.182128248360556
          ],
          [
            -76.60495754587669,
            39.18170387663917
          ],
          [
            -76.60502941936728,
            39.18128019065444
          ],
          [
            -76.60510839062077,
            39.180857261989246
          ],
          [
            -76.60519444629716,
            39.18043516209981
          ],
          [
            -76.60528757185979,
            39.180013962303626
          ],
          [
            -76.6053877515777,
            39.17959373376735
          ],
          [
            -76.60549496852833,
            39.17917454749487
          ],
          [
            -76.6056092046005,
            39.17875647431518
          ],
          [
            -76.60573044049717,
            39.178339584870486
          ],
          [
            -76.60585865573897,
            39.17792394960421
          ],
          [
            -76.60599382866758,
            39.17750963874914
          ],
          [
            -76.60617652627226,
            39.177121664458475
          ],
          [
            -76.60636490839762,
            39.17673532510915
          ],
          [
            -76.60655895063945,
            39.17635067077723
          ],
          [
            -76.60675862786046,
            39.17596775132125
          ],
          [
            -76.60696391419323,
            39.17558661637563
          ],
          [
            -76.60717478304375,
            39.17520731534431
          ],
          [
            -76.60739120709482,
            39.174829897394304
          ],
          [
            -76.60761315830962,
            39.17445441144932
          ],
          [
            -76.60784060793526,
            39.174080906183406
          ],
          [
            -76.60807352650656,
            39.17370943001463
          ],
          [
            -76.60816228715875,
            39.17349913171313
          ],
          [
            -76.60824421195713,
            39.17328717211977
          ],
          [
            -76.60831924929514,
            39.17307368473923
          ],
          [
            -76.60838735190463,
            39.1728588040397
          ],
          [
            -76.60844847688598,
            39.1726426653682
          ],
          [
            -76.60850258573491,
            39.17242540486535
          ],
          [
            -76.60854964436678,
            39.172207159379695
          ],
          [
            -76.60858962313806,
            39.17198806638144
          ],
          [
            -76.60862249686508,
            39.17176826387591
          ],
          [
            -76.60864824483978,
            39.171547890316674
          ],
          [
            -76.60866685084282,
            39.17132708451829
          ],
          [
            -76.60867830315375,
            39.17110598556889
          ],
          [
            -76.60868259455846,
            39.17088473274258
          ],
          [
            -76.6086797223537,
            39.17066346541173
          ],
          [
            -76.60866968834873,
            39.17044232295915
          ],
          [
            -76.60865249886422,
            39.17022144469028
          ],
          [
            -76.60862816472833,
            39.17000096974547
          ],
          [
            -76.60859670126976,
            39.16978103701233
          ],
          [
            -76.60855812830823,
            39.16956178503816
          ],
          [
            -76.60851247014186,
            39.16934335194274
          ],
          [
            -76.60845975553198,
            39.16912587533127
          ],
          [
            -76.60486484997955,
            39.160119126302206
          ],
          [
            -76.6031119623949,
            39.15567291444671
          ],
          [
            -76.60301746521947,
            39.155492180230205
          ],
          [
            -76.6029171958774,
            39.15531332546758
          ],
          [
            -76.6028112165009,
            39.15513646100156
          ],
          [
            -76.60269959276044,
            39.15496169644217
          ],
          [
            -76.60258239382402,
            39.15478914009891
          ],
          [
            -76.60245969231435,
            39.154618898913505
          ],
          [
            -76.60233156426384,
            39.15445107839363
          ],
          [
            -76.60219808906741,
            39.15428578254751
          ],
          [
            -76.60205934943343,
            39.154123113819416
          ],
          [
            -76.60191543133236,
            39.15396317302611
          ],
          [
            -76.60176642394347,
            39.15380605929436
          ],
          [
            -76.60161241959973,
            39.153651869999464
          ],
          [
            -76.60145351373039,
            39.153500700704846
          ],
          [
            -76.60128980480201,
            39.1533526451028
          ],
          [
            -76.60112139425733,
            39.15320779495642
          ],
          [
            -76.60096054494588,
            39.153103629654076
          ],
          [
            -76.60080411502742,
            39.15299549255137
          ],
          [
            -76.60065226750757,
            39.15288349631307
          ],
          [
            -76.60050516061695,
            39.15276775762517
          ],
          [
            -76.60036294764629,
            39.15264839707341
          ],
          [
            -76.60022577678663,
            39.15252553901769
          ],
          [
            -76.60009379097497,
            39.15239931146259
          ],
          [
            -76.59996712774533,
            39.152269845923996
          ],
          [
            -76.59984591908535,
            39.15213727729223
          ],
          [
            -76.59973029129885,
            39.15200174369145
          ],
          [
            -76.5996203648742,
            39.151863386335854
          ],
          [
            -76.59951625435865,
            39.1517223493826
          ],
          [
            -76.5994180682392,
            39.15157877978164
          ],
          [
            -76.5993259088293,
            39.15143282712265
          ],
          [
            -76.59923987216239,
            39.15128464347925
          ],
          [
            -76.59916004789181,
            39.15113438325055
          ],
          [
            -76.59908651919733,
            39.15098220300037
          ],
          [
            -76.59901936269851,
            39.1508282612941
          ],
          [
            -76.59895864837488,
            39.150672718533535
          ],
          [
            -76.59890443949291,
            39.15051573678981
          ],
          [
            -76.59885679254026,
            39.15035747963449
          ],
          [
            -76.59881575716676,
            39.15019811196923
          ],
          [
            -76.59878137613276,
            39.15003779985392
          ],
          [
            -76.59875368526457,
            39.14987671033372
          ],
          [
            -76.59873271341702,
            39.14971501126499
          ],
          [
            -76.59871354523216,
            39.14954117895811
          ],
          [
            -76.5987007594645,
            39.1493669937907
          ],
          [
            -76.59869436645675,
            39.14919259666234
          ],
          [
            -76.59869437138029,
            39.14901812864508
          ],
          [
            -76.59870077423113,
            39.14884373086941
          ],
          [
            -76.59871356982994,
            39.148669544410005
          ],
          [
            -76.59873274782606,
            39.14849571017167
          ],
          [
            -76.59875829270608,
            39.14832236877533
          ],
          [
            -76.59879018380626,
            39.148149660444254
          ],
          [
            -76.59882839532929,
            39.147977724890644
          ],
          [
            -76.59887289636515,
            39.14780670120258
          ],
          [
            -76.5989236509161,
            39.147636727731495
          ],
          [
            -76.59898061792586,
            39.14746794198023
          ],
          [
            -76.59904375131272,
            39.14730048049179
          ],
          [
            -76.59911300000688,
            39.14713447873889
          ],
          [
            -76.59915824935317,
            39.14697040897072
          ],
          [
            -76.59919686808175,
            39.14680532269757
          ],
          [
            -76.59922881850031,
            39.146639381038824
          ],
          [
            -76.59925406942494,
            39.14647274594983
          ],
          [
            -76.59927259621044,
            39.14630558006388
          ],
          [
            -76.59928438077446,
            39.14613804653345
          ],
          [
            -76.59928941161517,
            39.145970308871036
          ],
          [
            -76.59928768382242,
            39.145802530789496
          ],
          [
            -76.59927919908253,
            39.14563487604232
          ],
          [
            -76.5992639656767,
            39.14546750826381
          ],
          [
            -76.5992419984729,
            39.14530059080933
          ],
          [
            -76.59921331891135,
            39.14513428659586
          ],
          [
            -76.59917795498362,
            39.14496875794305
          ],
          [
            -76.59913594120529,
            39.144804166414616
          ],
          [
            -76.5990873185822,
            39.14464067266083
          ],
          [
            -76.59903213457062,
            39.14447843626152
          ],
          [
            -76.5989704430307,
            39.144317615570394
          ],
          [
            -76.59890230417403,
            39.14415836756038
          ],
          [
            -76.59882778450488,
            39.144000847670455
          ],
          [
            -76.59871039511414,
            39.14381296339047
          ],
          [
            -76.59858666171772,
            39.143627543371956
          ],
          [
            -76.59845667027793,
            39.14344471645316
          ],
          [
            -76.5983205111047,
            39.143264609671554
          ],
          [
            -76.59817827879294,
            39.14308734817545
          ],
          [
            -76.59803007215685,
            39.14291305513707
          ],
          [
            -76.59787599416107,
            39.142741851666834
          ],
          [
            -76.59771615184947,
            39.14257385672924
          ],
          [
            -76.5975506562705,
            39.14240918706008
          ],
          [
            -76.59737962240017,
            39.14224795708532
          ],
          [
            -76.5972031690622,
            39.14209027884153
          ],
          [
            -76.59702141884533,
            39.141936261897946
          ],
          [
            -76.58825103712245,
            39.1346544258951
          ],
          [
            -76.58045276453394,
            39.127224334409114
          ],
          [
            -76.57774321632357,
            39.1244032753277
          ],
          [
            -76.57760321539834,
            39.12426195154371
          ],
          [
            -76.57745790588315,
            39.124123890127386
          ],
          [
            -76.57730741404438,
            39.12398921106639
          ],
          [
            -76.57715187065149,
            39.123858031409476
          ],
          [
            -76.57699141086356,
            39.12373046516474
          ],
          [
            -76.57682617411169,
            39.123606623200494
          ],
          [
            -76.57665630397794,
            39.123486613148806
          ],
          [
            -76.57648194807055,
            39.12337053931196
          ],
          [
            -76.57630325789565,
            39.12325850257174
          ],
          [
            -76.5761203887256,
            39.123150600301656
          ],
          [
            -76.57593349946411,
            39.123046926282356
          ],
          [
            -76.57574275250816,
            39.12294757061994
          ],
          [
            -76.5755483136068,
            39.12285261966775
          ],
          [
            -76.57535035171726,
            39.122762155951136
          ],
          [
            -76.575149038858,
            39.12267625809573
          ],
          [
            -76.57494454995934,
            39.122595000759134
          ],
          [
            -76.57473706271138,
            39.12251845456585
          ],
          [
            -76.57452675740966,
            39.122446686045976
          ],
          [
            -76.57431381679844,
            39.12237975757727
          ],
          [
            -76.5740984259119,
            39.12231772733094
          ],
          [
            -76.57388077191345,
            39.12226064922102
          ],
          [
            -76.57366104393296,
            39.122208572857474
          ],
          [
            -76.57343943290253,
            39.12216154350309
          ],
          [
            -76.57321613139048,
            39.12211960203402
          ],
          [
            -76.57299133343412,
            39.12208278490434
          ],
          [
            -76.57276523437105,
            39.12205112411425
          ],
          [
            -76.57253803066949,
            39.122024647182286
          ],
          [
            -76.57183568648361,
            39.121947169632264
          ],
          [
            -76.57113247288498,
            39.121874593548064
          ],
          [
            -76.57042844670683,
            39.12180692481037
          ],
          [
            -76.56972366484807,
            39.12174416890229
          ],
          [
            -76.56901818426863,
            39.12168633090883
          ],
          [
            -76.568312061985,
            39.12163341551655
          ],
          [
            -76.56760535506547,
            39.121585427013116
          ],
          [
            -76.56689812062557,
            39.12154236928701
          ],
          [
            -76.56619041582351,
            39.121504245827175
          ],
          [
            -76.5654822978555,
            39.121471059722715
          ],
          [
            -76.56477382395111,
            39.1214428136627
          ],
          [
            -76.5640650513687,
            39.121419509935905
          ],
          [
            -76.56335603739079,
            39.12140115043062
          ],
          [
            -76.56264683931936,
            39.12138773663452
          ],
          [
            -76.56193751447134,
            39.12137926963451
          ],
          [
            -76.561446305482,
            39.12137129928427
          ],
          [
            -76.56095500521809,
            39.12136820885034
          ],
          [
            -76.5604636942228,
            39.12136999884
          ],
          [
            -76.55997245304108,
            39.121376668959456
          ],
          [
            -76.5594813622064,
            39.12138821811379
          ],
          [
            -76.5589905022276,
            39.12140464440728
          ],
          [
            -76.55849995357568,
            39.12142594514358
          ],
          [
            -76.55800979667058,
            39.12145211682627
          ],
          [
            -76.55752011186806,
            39.12148315515939
          ],
          [
            -76.55703097944644,
            39.12151905504809
          ],
          [
            -76.55654247959352,
            39.121559810599564
          ],
          [
            -76.55605469239333,
            39.121605415123994
          ],
          [
            -76.55556769781317,
            39.121655861135615
          ],
          [
            -76.55521308611485,
            39.1216939692341
          ],
          [
            -76.55485762075449,
            39.121726944806795
          ],
          [
            -76.55450142514484,
            39.12175477641226
          ],
          [
            -76.5541446229521,
            39.121777454393836
          ],
          [
            -76.55378733805308,
            39.12179497088303
          ],
          [
            -76.55342969449222,
            39.12180731980219
          ],
          [
            -76.55307181643845,
            39.12181449686667
          ],
          [
            -76.55271382814212,
            39.121816499586274
          ],
          [
            -76.55235585389184,
            39.121813327266125
          ],
          [
            -76.55199801797136,
            39.12180498100691
          ],
          [
            -76.5516404446164,
            39.121791463704504
          ],
          [
            -76.55128325797153,
            39.121772780048936
          ],
          [
            -76.55092658204705,
            39.12174893652283
          ],
          [
            -76.55057054067593,
            39.12171994139908
          ],
          [
            -76.55021525747088,
            39.121685804738036
          ],
          [
            -76.5498608557813,
            39.12164653838404
          ],
          [
            -76.54950745865065,
            39.12160215596124
          ],
          [
            -76.53496304390565,
            39.12008273370951
          ],
          [
            -76.52618315525284,
            39.119164425733
          ],
          [
            -76.52569014311455,
            39.11910232710676
          ],
          [
            -76.52519606567124,
            39.11904555304786
          ],
          [
            -76.52470101845684,
            39.118994114546915
          ],
          [
            -76.52420509719285,
            39.11894802156168
          ],
          [
            -76.52370839776971,
            39.118907283015105
          ],
          [
            -76.52321101622839,
            39.11887190679364
          ],
          [
            -76.5227130487417,
            39.11884189974564
          ],
          [
            -76.52221459159581,
            39.11881726768008
          ],
          [
            -76.52171574117148,
            39.118798015365414
          ],
          [
            -76.52121659392559,
            39.11878414652864
          ],
          [
            -76.52071724637237,
            39.118775663854606
          ],
          [
            -76.5202177950648,
            39.11877256898544
          ],
          [
            -76.51971833657592,
            39.11877486252028
          ],
          [
            -76.51921896748017,
            39.11878254401512
          ],
          [
            -76.51871978433466,
            39.11879561198292
          ],
          [
            -76.51822088366062,
            39.118814063893886
          ],
          [
            -76.51123310027648,
            39.11898002522117
          ],
          [
            -76.5107994396434,
            39.11897479749558
          ],
          [
            -76.51036593336157,
            39.11896441021431
          ],
          [
            -76.50993268340919,
            39.11894886581861
          ],
          [
            -76.50949979170417,
            39.11892816796172
          ],
          [
            -76.50911835443813,
            39.118905638880555
          ],
          [
            -76.50873734489493,
            39.118879108572635
          ],
          [
            -76.50835683280118,
            39.11884858188862
          ],
          [
            -76.50797688779258,
            39.11881406440987
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 17,
        "Contract_N": "AT0625124",
        "SHAPE_Leng": "53224.7785428",
        "Completion": "100"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Here's some information in the documentation, complete with a usage example: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson `aT0625124projectlimits` will be your `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can simply be done in one `html` file. You have to use [L.geoJson](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson) function. Check out the code snippet:

```js
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([39.10, -76.60], 12);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

var aT0625124projectlimits = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-76.60064603515116,
          39.2066837882357
        ],
        [-76.6008535248809,
          39.20570326707206
        ],
        [-76.60105527000235,
          39.20472201267091
        ],
        [-76.60125126636073,
          39.203740045211056
        ],
        [-76.60144150991955,
          39.20275738488675
        ],
        [-76.60162599676089,
          39.201774051907414
        ],
        [-76.6018047230853,
          39.2007900664971
        ],
        [-76.60299312179492,
          39.193882732157995
        ],
        [-76.60483513954705,
          39.18255323412114
        ],
        [-76.60489278228994,
          39.182128248360556
        ],
        [-76.60495754587669,
          39.18170387663917
        ],
        [-76.60502941936728,
          39.18128019065444
        ],
        [-76.60510839062077,
          39.180857261989246
        ],
        [-76.60519444629716,
          39.18043516209981
        ],
        [-76.60528757185979,
          39.180013962303626
        ],
        [-76.6053877515777,
          39.17959373376735
        ],
        [-76.60549496852833,
          39.17917454749487
        ],
        [-76.6056092046005,
          39.17875647431518
        ],
        [-76.60573044049717,
          39.178339584870486
        ],
        [-76.60585865573897,
          39.17792394960421
        ],
        [-76.60599382866758,
          39.17750963874914
        ],
        [-76.60617652627226,
          39.177121664458475
        ],
        [-76.60636490839762,
          39.17673532510915
        ],
        [-76.60655895063945,
          39.17635067077723
        ],
        [-76.60675862786046,
          39.17596775132125
        ],
        [-76.60696391419323,
          39.17558661637563
        ],
        [-76.60717478304375,
          39.17520731534431
        ],
        [-76.60739120709482,
          39.174829897394304
        ],
        [-76.60761315830962,
          39.17445441144932
        ],
        [-76.60784060793526,
          39.174080906183406
        ],
        [-76.60807352650656,
          39.17370943001463
        ],
        [-76.60816228715875,
          39.17349913171313
        ],
        [-76.60824421195713,
          39.17328717211977
        ],
        [-76.60831924929514,
          39.17307368473923
        ],
        [-76.60838735190463,
          39.1728588040397
        ],
        [-76.60844847688598,
          39.1726426653682
        ],
        [-76.60850258573491,
          39.17242540486535
        ],
        [-76.60854964436678,
          39.172207159379695
        ],
        [-76.60858962313806,
          39.17198806638144
        ],
        [-76.60862249686508,
          39.17176826387591
        ],
        [-76.60864824483978,
          39.171547890316674
        ],
        [-76.60866685084282,
          39.17132708451829
        ],
        [-76.60867830315375,
          39.17110598556889
        ],
        [-76.60868259455846,
          39.17088473274258
        ],
        [-76.6086797223537,
          39.17066346541173
        ],
        [-76.60866968834873,
          39.17044232295915
        ],
        [-76.60865249886422,
          39.17022144469028
        ],
        [-76.60862816472833,
          39.17000096974547
        ],
        [-76.60859670126976,
          39.16978103701233
        ],
        [-76.60855812830823,
          39.16956178503816
        ],
        [-76.60851247014186,
          39.16934335194274
        ],
        [-76.60845975553198,
          39.16912587533127
        ],
        [-76.60486484997955,
          39.160119126302206
        ],
        [-76.6031119623949,
          39.15567291444671
        ],
        [-76.60301746521947,
          39.155492180230205
        ],
        [-76.6029171958774,
          39.15531332546758
        ],
        [-76.6028112165009,
          39.15513646100156
        ],
        [-76.60269959276044,
          39.15496169644217
        ],
        [-76.60258239382402,
          39.15478914009891
        ],
        [-76.60245969231435,
          39.154618898913505
        ],
        [-76.60233156426384,
          39.15445107839363
        ],
        [-76.60219808906741,
          39.15428578254751
        ],
        [-76.60205934943343,
          39.154123113819416
        ],
        [-76.60191543133236,
          39.15396317302611
        ],
        [-76.60176642394347,
          39.15380605929436
        ],
        [-76.60161241959973,
          39.153651869999464
        ],
        [-76.60145351373039,
          39.153500700704846
        ],
        [-76.60128980480201,
          39.1533526451028
        ],
        [-76.60112139425733,
          39.15320779495642
        ],
        [-76.60096054494588,
          39.153103629654076
        ],
        [-76.60080411502742,
          39.15299549255137
        ],
        [-76.60065226750757,
          39.15288349631307
        ],
        [-76.60050516061695,
          39.15276775762517
        ],
        [-76.60036294764629,
          39.15264839707341
        ],
        [-76.60022577678663,
          39.15252553901769
        ],
        [-76.60009379097497,
          39.15239931146259
        ],
        [-76.59996712774533,
          39.152269845923996
        ],
        [-76.59984591908535,
          39.15213727729223
        ],
        [-76.59973029129885,
          39.15200174369145
        ],
        [-76.5996203648742,
          39.151863386335854
        ],
        [-76.59951625435865,
          39.1517223493826
        ],
        [-76.5994180682392,
          39.15157877978164
        ],
        [-76.5993259088293,
          39.15143282712265
        ],
        [-76.59923987216239,
          39.15128464347925
        ],
        [-76.59916004789181,
          39.15113438325055
        ],
        [-76.59908651919733,
          39.15098220300037
        ],
        [-76.59901936269851,
          39.1508282612941
        ],
        [-76.59895864837488,
          39.150672718533535
        ],
        [-76.59890443949291,
          39.15051573678981
        ],
        [-76.59885679254026,
          39.15035747963449
        ],
        [-76.59881575716676,
          39.15019811196923
        ],
        [-76.59878137613276,
          39.15003779985392
        ],
        [-76.59875368526457,
          39.14987671033372
        ],
        [-76.59873271341702,
          39.14971501126499
        ],
        [-76.59871354523216,
          39.14954117895811
        ],
        [-76.5987007594645,
          39.1493669937907
        ],
        [-76.59869436645675,
          39.14919259666234
        ],
        [-76.59869437138029,
          39.14901812864508
        ],
        [-76.59870077423113,
          39.14884373086941
        ],
        [-76.59871356982994,
          39.148669544410005
        ],
        [-76.59873274782606,
          39.14849571017167
        ],
        [-76.59875829270608,
          39.14832236877533
        ],
        [-76.59879018380626,
          39.148149660444254
        ],
        [-76.59882839532929,
          39.147977724890644
        ],
        [-76.59887289636515,
          39.14780670120258
        ],
        [-76.5989236509161,
          39.147636727731495
        ],
        [-76.59898061792586,
          39.14746794198023
        ],
        [-76.59904375131272,
          39.14730048049179
        ],
        [-76.59911300000688,
          39.14713447873889
        ],
        [-76.59915824935317,
          39.14697040897072
        ],
        [-76.59919686808175,
          39.14680532269757
        ],
        [-76.59922881850031,
          39.146639381038824
        ],
        [-76.59925406942494,
          39.14647274594983
        ],
        [-76.59927259621044,
          39.14630558006388
        ],
        [-76.59928438077446,
          39.14613804653345
        ],
        [-76.59928941161517,
          39.145970308871036
        ],
        [-76.59928768382242,
          39.145802530789496
        ],
        [-76.59927919908253,
          39.14563487604232
        ],
        [-76.5992639656767,
          39.14546750826381
        ],
        [-76.5992419984729,
          39.14530059080933
        ],
        [-76.59921331891135,
          39.14513428659586
        ],
        [-76.59917795498362,
          39.14496875794305
        ],
        [-76.59913594120529,
          39.144804166414616
        ],
        [-76.5990873185822,
          39.14464067266083
        ],
        [-76.59903213457062,
          39.14447843626152
        ],
        [-76.5989704430307,
          39.144317615570394
        ],
        [-76.59890230417403,
          39.14415836756038
        ],
        [-76.59882778450488,
          39.144000847670455
        ],
        [-76.59871039511414,
          39.14381296339047
        ],
        [-76.59858666171772,
          39.143627543371956
        ],
        [-76.59845667027793,
          39.14344471645316
        ],
        [-76.5983205111047,
          39.143264609671554
        ],
        [-76.59817827879294,
          39.14308734817545
        ],
        [-76.59803007215685,
          39.14291305513707
        ],
        [-76.59787599416107,
          39.142741851666834
        ],
        [-76.59771615184947,
          39.14257385672924
        ],
        [-76.5975506562705,
          39.14240918706008
        ],
        [-76.59737962240017,
          39.14224795708532
        ],
        [-76.5972031690622,
          39.14209027884153
        ],
        [-76.59702141884533,
          39.141936261897946
        ],
        [-76.58825103712245,
          39.1346544258951
        ],
        [-76.58045276453394,
          39.127224334409114
        ],
        [-76.57774321632357,
          39.1244032753277
        ],
        [-76.57760321539834,
          39.12426195154371
        ],
        [-76.57745790588315,
          39.124123890127386
        ],
        [-76.57730741404438,
          39.12398921106639
        ],
        [-76.57715187065149,
          39.123858031409476
        ],
        [-76.57699141086356,
          39.12373046516474
        ],
        [-76.57682617411169,
          39.123606623200494
        ],
        [-76.57665630397794,
          39.123486613148806
        ],
        [-76.57648194807055,
          39.12337053931196
        ],
        [-76.57630325789565,
          39.12325850257174
        ],
        [-76.5761203887256,
          39.123150600301656
        ],
        [-76.57593349946411,
          39.123046926282356
        ],
        [-76.57574275250816,
          39.12294757061994
        ],
        [-76.5755483136068,
          39.12285261966775
        ],
        [-76.57535035171726,
          39.122762155951136
        ],
        [-76.575149038858,
          39.12267625809573
        ],
        [-76.57494454995934,
          39.122595000759134
        ],
        [-76.57473706271138,
          39.12251845456585
        ],
        [-76.57452675740966,
          39.122446686045976
        ],
        [-76.57431381679844,
          39.12237975757727
        ],
        [-76.5740984259119,
          39.12231772733094
        ],
        [-76.57388077191345,
          39.12226064922102
        ],
        [-76.57366104393296,
          39.122208572857474
        ],
        [-76.57343943290253,
          39.12216154350309
        ],
        [-76.57321613139048,
          39.12211960203402
        ],
        [-76.57299133343412,
          39.12208278490434
        ],
        [-76.57276523437105,
          39.12205112411425
        ],
        [-76.57253803066949,
          39.122024647182286
        ],
        [-76.57183568648361,
          39.121947169632264
        ],
        [-76.57113247288498,
          39.121874593548064
        ],
        [-76.57042844670683,
          39.12180692481037
        ],
        [-76.56972366484807,
          39.12174416890229
        ],
        [-76.56901818426863,
          39.12168633090883
        ],
        [-76.568312061985,
          39.12163341551655
        ],
        [-76.56760535506547,
          39.121585427013116
        ],
        [-76.56689812062557,
          39.12154236928701
        ],
        [-76.56619041582351,
          39.121504245827175
        ],
        [-76.5654822978555,
          39.121471059722715
        ],
        [-76.56477382395111,
          39.1214428136627
        ],
        [-76.5640650513687,
          39.121419509935905
        ],
        [-76.56335603739079,
          39.12140115043062
        ],
        [-76.56264683931936,
          39.12138773663452
        ],
        [-76.56193751447134,
          39.12137926963451
        ],
        [-76.561446305482,
          39.12137129928427
        ],
        [-76.56095500521809,
          39.12136820885034
        ],
        [-76.5604636942228,
          39.12136999884
        ],
        [-76.55997245304108,
          39.121376668959456
        ],
        [-76.5594813622064,
          39.12138821811379
        ],
        [-76.5589905022276,
          39.12140464440728
        ],
        [-76.55849995357568,
          39.12142594514358
        ],
        [-76.55800979667058,
          39.12145211682627
        ],
        [-76.55752011186806,
          39.12148315515939
        ],
        [-76.55703097944644,
          39.12151905504809
        ],
        [-76.55654247959352,
          39.121559810599564
        ],
        [-76.55605469239333,
          39.121605415123994
        ],
        [-76.55556769781317,
          39.121655861135615
        ],
        [-76.55521308611485,
          39.1216939692341
        ],
        [-76.55485762075449,
          39.121726944806795
        ],
        [-76.55450142514484,
          39.12175477641226
        ],
        [-76.5541446229521,
          39.121777454393836
        ],
        [-76.55378733805308,
          39.12179497088303
        ],
        [-76.55342969449222,
          39.12180731980219
        ],
        [-76.55307181643845,
          39.12181449686667
        ],
        [-76.55271382814212,
          39.121816499586274
        ],
        [-76.55235585389184,
          39.121813327266125
        ],
        [-76.55199801797136,
          39.12180498100691
        ],
        [-76.5516404446164,
          39.121791463704504
        ],
        [-76.55128325797153,
          39.121772780048936
        ],
        [-76.55092658204705,
          39.12174893652283
        ],
        [-76.55057054067593,
          39.12171994139908
        ],
        [-76.55021525747088,
          39.121685804738036
        ],
        [-76.5498608557813,
          39.12164653838404
        ],
        [-76.54950745865065,
          39.12160215596124
        ],
        [-76.53496304390565,
          39.12008273370951
        ],
        [-76.52618315525284,
          39.119164425733
        ],
        [-76.52569014311455,
          39.11910232710676
        ],
        [-76.52519606567124,
          39.11904555304786
        ],
        [-76.52470101845684,
          39.118994114546915
        ],
        [-76.52420509719285,
          39.11894802156168
        ],
        [-76.52370839776971,
          39.118907283015105
        ],
        [-76.52321101622839,
          39.11887190679364
        ],
        [-76.5227130487417,
          39.11884189974564
        ],
        [-76.52221459159581,
          39.11881726768008
        ],
        [-76.52171574117148,
          39.118798015365414
        ],
        [-76.52121659392559,
          39.11878414652864
        ],
        [-76.52071724637237,
          39.118775663854606
        ],
        [-76.5202177950648,
          39.11877256898544
        ],
        [-76.51971833657592,
          39.11877486252028
        ],
        [-76.51921896748017,
          39.11878254401512
        ],
        [-76.51871978433466,
          39.11879561198292
        ],
        [-76.51822088366062,
          39.118814063893886
        ],
        [-76.51123310027648,
          39.11898002522117
        ],
        [-76.5107994396434,
          39.11897479749558
        ],
        [-76.51036593336157,
          39.11896441021431
        ],
        [-76.50993268340919,
          39.11894886581861
        ],
        [-76.50949979170417,
          39.11892816796172
        ],
        [-76.50911835443813,
          39.118905638880555
        ],
        [-76.50873734489493,
          39.118879108572635
        ],
        [-76.50835683280118,
          39.11884858188862
        ],
        [-76.50797688779258,
          39.11881406440987
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 17,
      "Contract_N": "AT0625124",
      "SHAPE_Leng": "53224.7785428",
      "Completion": "100"
    }
  }]
}

L.geoJson(aT0625124projectlimits, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      stroke: true,
      color: "red",
      weight: 5
    };
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("id: " + feature.properties.OBJECTID + "<br>" +
      "Contract_N: " + feature.properties.Contract_N);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Leaflet polyline with popup</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Or check out the example on codepen: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/NdJJBJ